# I have a Photoshop .pat file, but I don't have Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns

I bought some textured patterns I'd like to use in an iOS app I'm developing, but they're in .pat and .mxp formats. I don't own any of the Adobe apps (Photoshop, Fireworks, inDesign, whatever).

Can I do anything with them, or have I wasted my money?

Comment: You can always download a photoshop trial, which will last long enough for you to extract the patterns.  http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=photoshop ( cs 6 extended trial )

Comment: what image editing software do you have available to you?

Comment: What software **DO** you have?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to open and use them with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/). It's free.

> Bitmap image used as a pattern that can be imported into multiple graphics programs; typically a square file that may be 8x8 pixels to 256x256 pixels in size; repeats to fill an area with the pattern; often used for creating a textured background.

Source: http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/pat

Comment: Might work, but: http://gimp.open-source-solution.org/manual/gimp-concepts-patterns.html "Caution
Do not confuse GIMP-generated .pat files with files created by other programs (e.g. Photoshop) – after all, .pat is just a part of an (arbitrary) file name.

(However, GIMP does support Photoshop .pat files until a certain version.)"

Comment: I've tried using GIMP, I lasted about fifteen seconds before getting it the heck off my machine, it has the most horrendous UI I've ever seen. I suppose I might have to give it another go..

Comment: And "until a certain version" in their own help documentation? How useless is that?! Sorry, venting frustration on useless software, but I can't see how it can import a .pat anyway, there's no Import, Open can't do it, dragging it in does nothing.. hmm.

Comment: there is a plugin for 2.4 that purportedly works for 2.8 gimp, but you'd need to compile it(!) google "gimp 2.8 pat photoshop loader" see also "ps-pat-load_1.c"

Comment: Then I suggest to go with Joonas idea to use the trial version. That's simply the problem with free software; sometimes it is not as advanced as the expensive market leader.

Comment: I feel the problem with open source software is that it's built by 90% coders, and perhaps 2% designers and almost zero UX thought, while successful market leaders invest early into UX/UI & design.

Comment: That maybe true. In this case it's all about handling one single file, for which it might just be enough.